# Transpiling next.js server code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a fresh install of Next.js and am wanting to be able to use `import` and `async/await` etc.

I have updated my .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["."],
        "alias": {
          "styles": "./styles"
        },
        "cwd": "babelrc"
      }
    ],
    [
      "wrap-in-js",
      {
        "extensions": ["css$"]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "presets": [
    "next/babel",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
  ],
  "ignore": []
}
```

I assume I need to update some config to `./server.js`?

Also how do I get around starting my app as I can point my start script to run from `./dist/server` but I believe the server needs to run to be able to run a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a fresh install of Next.js and am wanting to be able to use import and async/await etc.

I believe async/await works on the current release without an modification, but dynamic import requires the v3 beta:

```
npm install next.js@beta
```

See https://zeit.co/blog/next3-preview

> Also how do I get around starting my app as I can point my start script to run from ./dist/server but I believe the server needs to run to be able to run a build?

Normally, you run `npm run dev` (which is aliased to `next`) for development and `npm run build; npm start` (which aliases to `next build; next start`) for production. You wouldn't directly run any JS file.

If you want to run a custom server, then you would start your server file directly (`node myserver.js` or whatever) and have it start next programatically. See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master#custom-server-and-routing for more info on that.